# How to save user input data to redis using tornado python

Tags: python, redis, tornado

I am writing a small web app using tornado, python, below is my code. I have a html form in python with 2 text fields, now I want to take the input form the text fields and store in redis.
My questions -

1. How do I make a connection to redis from my python script?
2. How do I store the incoming user inputs into redis?

Example code would be appreciated.

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

from tornado.options import define, options

define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('<html><body><form action="/" method="post">'
           '<p>Please enter the Key Value pair for redis.</p>'
                   '<input type="text" **name="key"** value="type key here">'
           '<input type="text" **name="value"** value="type value here">'
                   '<input type="submit" value="Submit Key Value">'
                   '</form></body></html>')


def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What about the python redis module to connect to redis, the redis documentation for the methods and tornado's documentation regarding POST handling?

Answer (score 3):

For the 1st question, using python's redis module.

Firstly, install `redis` from `sudo easy_install redis` or get the [source code](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/zipball/master) to install it from setup script

There are documentations on py-redis's [github page](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py), but if you want to start with something simple, just write these 2 lines of code:

```
import redis
# if your redis was implemented properly and defaultly (eg. on 6379 port),
# `db` you get can work now.
db = redis.StrictRedis()
```

For 2nd question, write HTTP POST handling method on `MainHandler`:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ...

    def post(self):
        # use handler's get_argument method to get incoming data,
        # if eithor of them is not get, a HTTP 400 will return
        key = self.get_argument('key')
        value = self.get_argument('value')
        # just like `SET` command in redis client
        db.set(key, value)
        # return something you want
        self.write('Set %s - %s pair OK' % (key, value))
```

PS. you can set `db` as an attribute previously to you handler class so that it can be easily get from `self.db`.